# How to configure OLinuXino Lime UART's using DTB

Tags: uart, device-tree

How do I configure the UART's in the OLinuXino Lime using a DTB file? I'm using the image from http://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/A10-OLinuXino-LIME.

UART 0 is already configured. This is the relevant part from the DTS file, if I understand correctly:

```
uart0: serial@01c28000 {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&uart0_pins_a>;
        status = "okay";
};
```

From http://linux-sunxi.org/Memory_map I can get the memory space for the other UART's. But where do I get the syntax for the pinctrl-0 field, for instance?

Can we configure the hardware with the DTB file only with no need for Allwinner's FEX file?

In an "ideal" situation, should the DTB files be configured by the hardware manufacturer or should they be configured by the developer (is there a manual)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use Allwinner's FEX file or Open Firmware's Device Tree (DT).

Add these lines to the DT source file (DTS) and compile with dtc.

```
uart2: serial@01c28800 {
  pinctrl-names = "default";
  pinctrl-0 = <&uart2_pins_a>;
  status = "okay";
};
```